# Adding spaces between strings after sum()

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming that I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({ 'X':['a','b'], 'Y':['c','d'], 'Z':['e','f']})  
   X Y Z
 0 a c e
 1 b d f
```

The desired output is:

```
0    a c e
1    b d f
```

When I run the following code, I get:

```
>>> data.sum(axis=1)
0    ace
1    bdf
```

So how do I add columns of strings with space between them?

Comment: What is "the following code"?

Comment: @user2314737 - I think `df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael yes, added the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) per rows by `axis=1` and `join`:

```
a = data.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
print (a)
0    a c e
1    b d f
dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) spaces, [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and last [`str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
a = data.add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip()
#same as
#a = (data + ' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip()
print (a)
0    a c e
1    b d f
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow :

```
data.apply(lambda x:x + ' ').sum(axis=1)
```

The output is :

```
0    a c e 
1    b d f 
dtype: object
```