# Pandas dataframe Merge text rows group by ID

Tags: python-3.x, merge, excel-formula, pandas-groupby, text-mining

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID    Date          Text  
1     01/01/2019    abcd
1     01/01/2019    pqrs
2     01/02/2019    abcd
2     01/02/2019    xyze
```

I want to merge `Text` by `ID` in Python using group by clause.

I want to merge '`Text`' columns by grouping `ID`.

```
ID    Date        Text
1     01/01/2019  abcdpqrs
2     01/02/2019  abcdxyze
```

I want to do this in Python.

I have attempted following code chunks but it didn't work:

1. `groups = groupby(dataset_new, key=ID(1))`
2. `dataset_new.group_by{row['Reference']}.values.each do |group| 
   puts [group.first['Reference'], group.map{|r| r['Text']} * ' '] * ' | ' 
   end`

I also attempted to merge text in excel using formulas but it is also not giving required results.

Comment: Any suggestions guys..

Comment: Any suggestions @Daniel.E

Comment: I hope someone answers it !:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupby` and `sum`. Judging from your error message and the output of `df.info()` it seems there are mixed dtypes and `NaN` in column `Text`. I suggest converting `NaN` to empty string using `fillna('')`, then convert all elements in the column to string using `astype(str)`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2], 
                   'Date': ['01/01/2019', '01/01/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/02/2019'],
                   'Text': ['abcd', 'pqrs', 'abcd', 'xyze']})

df['Text'] = df['Text'].fillna('').astype(str)
df_grouped = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Text'].sum()
print(df_grouped)
```

This should return

```
ID  Date      
1   01/01/2019    abcdpqrs
2   01/02/2019    abcdxyze
```

Comment: Hi @WolfgangK - getting error - "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str."

Comment: I attempted : df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])str(['Text']).sum() - didn't work.

Comment: RangeIndex:         125 entries, 0 to 124                                                                    
    Data columns        (total 3 columns):
    Date Created        12520 non-null object
    Reference             12520 non-null object
    Text                       12518 non-null object
    dtypes:                  object(3)

Comment: Hi @WolfgangK - Please find above details.

Comment: Excellent @WolfgangK !

Comment: how do I add a space when joining the text? basically I am looking `abcd pqrs`

Comment: @floss maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188605/adding-spaces-between-strings-after-sum